# Qt QTreeWidget - disabling interaction for a single column

Tags: c++, qt

is there a way to disable interaction or just sorting for a specific row in a `QTreeWidget`? I have a table where if you click the header, it sorts the items. I have a custom "`CTreeWidgetItem`" where I have overloaded the `< operator` to perform a custom sort on my data. The problem is, it sorts on every header I click, not just the first column. I need it to only work for the first column. Is there something I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply connect to the [`sectionClicked()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html#sectionClicked) signal of the header (`QTreeView::header()`). Then force the sort indicator back to the first section [`QHeaderView::setSortIndicator()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html#setSortIndicator).